# How to set Navigation in Office 365 site using powershell?

Tags: navigation, powershell

I am creating some Global / Current navigations nodes on a SharePoint site (SharePoint 2010 in house site) by fetching them through a csv file.

Below is the script:

```
#Script to create Global/Current navigation links 

$Web = Get-SPWeb "http://...."
$pubWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)

Function Set-SPGlobalNav($Links)
{

    $CreateNavigationNodeMethod = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.SPNavigationSiteMapNode]::CreateSPNavigationNode

        $inputFile = Import-CSV $Links

        foreach($row in $inputFile) {

            Write-Host “Adding the Link: ” $row.LinkTitle

        $qlNav = $pubWeb.Navigation.GlobalNavigationNodes

        $headingNode = $CreateNavigationNodeMethod.Invoke($row.LinkTitle, $row.LinkURL, [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.NodeTypes]::AuthoredLinkPlain, $qlNav) 
        $web.Update()       


        }
}

Set-SPGlobalNav -Links "c:\links.csv"
```

This is absolutely working fine in SharePoint 2010 site and creating navigation links as supplied in a CSV file.

Now I want same functionality in a office 365 site also. I have already done setup for SharePoint online management shell. and need to run similar kind of script. Kindly assist how can I achieve that as I am new in scripting.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, PowerShell for O365 is not going to accomplish that.  You can, however, use the [CSOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client(v=office.15).aspx) to accomplish this.  [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.navigationnode(v=office.15).aspx) link shows how to create a navigation node.  Here is the main part of it:

```
string siteUrl = "http://server/sites/MySiteCollection";

ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
Web site = clientContext.Web;

// Get the Quick Launch navigation node collection.
NavigationNodeCollection collQuickLaunchNode = site.Navigation.QuickLaunch;

// Set properties for a new navigation node.
NavigationNodeCreationInformation ciNavicationNode = new NavigationNodeCreationInformation();
ciNavicationNode.Title = "New Node";
ciNavicationNode.Url = "http://localhost";
// Create node as the last node in the collection.
ciNavicationNode.AsLastNode = true;
collQuickLaunchNode.Add(ciNavicationNode);

clientContext.Load(collQuickLaunchNode);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

You can either execute this in console, or you can execute it in PowerShell, as shown in [this](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/12/Using-CSOM-in-PowerShell-scripts-with-Office365.html) link (you need the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client(.Runtime) dll's from the ISAPI folder in 15 hive).
Here is what it would look like in PowerShell:

```
$username = "username"
$password = "password"
$url = "https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/appdev"
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force

Add-Type -Path (Join-Path ([System.Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")) "15 Hive\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll")
Add-Type -Path (Join-Path ([System.Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")) "15 Hive\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll")

$clientCtx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username,$securePassword)
$clientCtx.Credentials = $credentials

$web = $clientCtx.Web
$navColl = $web.Navigation.QuickLaunch
$newNavNode = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.NavigationNodeCreationInformation
$newNavNode.Title = "Node Title"
$newNavNode.Url = "http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com"
$newNavNode.AsLastNode = $true
$navColl.Add($newNavNode)
# I received an error after executing the above.  
# I ignored it and moved on, and executed the following lines.  
# The navigation node was added successfully, as shown in my screen cap.     
$clientCtx.Load($navColl)
$clientCtx.ExecuteQuery()
```

I got an error at `$navColl.Add($newNavNode)`, but after the `$clientCtx.ExecuteQuery()`, I checked my site, and the new navigation was there:

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks, I am looking for a powershell solution. Please tell me that how can I execute this in Powershell?

Comment: Added the PowerShell script

Comment: Hi While running the above script after editing my changes in the script (Like Url, username, password, dll path) I am getting below error in online shell management screen:format-default : The collection has not been initialized. It has not been
requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly
requested.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], CollectionNo
   tInitializedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CollectionNotInitial
   izedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand

Comment: Hi after some more modifying the script, script is running but, exactly on same step: $navColl.Add($newNavNode)
I am getting error and link is not added in the navigation: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\chsuser\Desktop\Final\Final\navigationoffice365.ps1:47 char:2
+     $navColl.Add($newNavNode)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull        Please help me on this issue.

Comment: @Chitransh I got the error too.  Like I said in my answer, I just continued on, and after the `$clientCtx.ExecuteQuery()`, I found that the node did get added to my site (as seen in the screen cap).

Comment: The error isn't because the action failed - but because powershell fails to write the object. Add | out-null behind the line to ignore the output error. http://spyankulov.blogspot.be/2014/08/display-csom-objects-in-powershell.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using,

```
collQuickLaunchNode.Add(ciNavicationNode);
clientContext.Load(collQuickLaunchNode);
```

use

```
clientContext.Load(collQuickLaunchNode.Add(ciNavicationNode))
```

This will solve the error

Comment: Can you provide some explanation on why this would solve his issue?